# Android: Hiding video in sd card and play it only in my application

Tags: android, security, media-player, android-mediaplayer

I am working on a application where-in I will be keeping the videos in my SD card and will play in my application. I do not want those videos to be copied by any means. Is there any way I can achieve this? One of the way I assume is via encryption and decryption.. Apart from this any other way?

Please suggest!

Comment: as long as you dont plan for 25 or 50 videos put them in the assets or raw folder, if you are planning on making the app pay to learn all inclusive api with a website. if your app is to large stocked with videos they have to pay to watch, many people wont download

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dominicd!  That any way I can do by keeping the contents in asset folder. But issue is size of Videos is in several GB. Also we dont need to keep those on any server. All the files will be available offline. My concern now is to save these videos from unauthorized access & at the same time to use it in my application. Any thoughts around this will be highly appreciated

Comment: you can encrypt these files and  when you want to play those file decrypt them  in a temp folder. at the end of play delete the temp file.

Comment: Thanks Mehd! This is one way to acheive which I too have in my mind! But apart from this do we have any other solution to achieve this?